# What's the error in my foreach loop over multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Following is my multidimensional array named `$prev_map_data`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 2
            [class_name] => II
            [class_checked] => 1
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 81
                            [subject_name] => 11 Engllish
                            [subject_checked] => 1
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 81
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [class_id] => 3
            [class_name] => III
            [class_checked] => 1
            [class_subjects] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 155
                            [subject_name] => Hidi
                            [subject_checked] => 1
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 155
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 156
                            [subject_name] => 11 Maths
                            [subject_checked] => 1
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 156
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [cs_map_id] => 157
                            [subject_name] => 11 Science
                            [subject_checked] => 1
                            [teacher_cs_id] => 157
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to get all the values from key `[cs_map_id]` one by one and push the values in an array `$data`. But getting the warning

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I'm not understanding what is wrong with my code. Can any one help me to improve my code and append the values to the new array? Thanks in advance. My code is as follows :

```
$prev_map_data  = $objTeacherClassesSubjects->GetClassSubjectMappingsbyTeacherId ($request, $teacher_class_subjects_error_messages);
//print_d($prev_map_data);
$data = array();
foreach($prev_map_data as $map_id){
    foreach($map_id as $ast){
        foreach($ast as $tp){
            //print_p($tp);
            $tp['cs_map_id'];
            array_push($data,$tp['cs_map_id']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It means one of the things you think is an array is actually not an array.

Comment: please format your code and add line number

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for your suggestion. I've given my existing multidimensional array for your reference. Seeing that can you correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are digging unconditionally into the array on items that are not themselves arrays. Do this instead:

```
foreach($prev_map_data as $map_id){
    foreach($map_id['class_subjects'] as $subject){
        $data[] = $subject['cs_map_id'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your trick worked for me. Thanks for it. When I tried to get the [class_id] in same fashion, it again gave me the same warning. Can you tell me what's wrong this time with my code? My code is 
foreach($prev_map_data as $map_id) {
              $cls_data[] = $map_id['class_id'];
          }

Comment: @phpLover: No idea. If it gave you the same warning and the only `foreach` is the one you mention, the only explanation is that `$prev_map_data` is not an array. But that does not make sense, at least with the information available.

Comment: Sorry Jon it was some syntactical mistake made by me, so it was giving a warning. After making correction it worked really fine for me. Thanks for your valuable help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$arr = array();

foreach($prev_map_data as $map_id){
   $i = 0;
   foreach($map_id['class_subjects'] as $val) {

       $arr[$i] = $val['cs_map_id'];
       $i++;
   }
}
```